# Get everything except special words

Tags: regex

I need a regex which match everything expect for several words.

The input-string is something like:

```
This&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;&ltTest$gt;
```

It should match

```
This Is A Test
```

So I want to have everything around `&nbsp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`

I've tried something like `[^&nbsp;]` to ignore all appearances of `&nbsp;` but this excludes every character.

Comment: What is the language? Do you mean you need to replace all `&nbsp;` with a space? Use a mere string replace method.

Comment: With PCRE, you may use [`&nbsp;(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!&nbsp;).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/GZl31C/1) if you want to match any text but some multicharacter string and get separate matches, like `['This', 'Is', 'A', 'Test']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Or even [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, They aren't trying to parse (X)HTML, they are trying to remove a set of known characters from a string.

Comment: @KyleFairns `&nbsp;` is an [**HTML** character entity reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: But the answer you are referring to is about the tags within HTML. This one is not

Answer (score 1):

```
/&[a-zA-Z]{2,8};/g
```

Breakdown:

- `&` - match & literally
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,8}` - match any characters in ranges `a-z` and `A-Z` from 2 to 8 times
- `;` - until a semi colon

The longest special character that you could encounter is `&thetasym;` - ϑ, and so I've taken this into account in the regex.

The proper formatting replaces each of the special characters with a space, and replaces multiple spaces in a row with a single space

```js
let regex = /&[a-zA-Z]{2,8};/g,
string = "This&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;&lt;Test&gt;",
properlyFormatted = string.replace(regex, " ").replace(/\ +/g, " ");

console.log(properlyFormatted);
```

**The alternative:**

```
/&(?:lt|gt|nbsp);/g
```

Breakdown:

- `&` - match & literally
- `(?:lt|gt|nbsp)` - match any group in `lt`, `gt`, `nbsp`
- `;` - directly followed by a semi colon

This regex will only take into account the specific characters you described.

```js
let regex = /&(?:lt|gt|nbsp);/g,
string = "This&nbsp;Is&nbsp;A&nbsp;&lt;Test&gt;",
properlyFormatted = string.replace(regex, " ").replace(/\ +/g, " ");

console.log(properlyFormatted);
```

Comment: This is really not generic and bad way of doing. You better use a HTML decoder library (that follow RFCs) instead of writing your own quick-and-dirty decoder.

Comment: Added a specific example on how to get rid of the 3 special chars that need to be gotten rid of. The generic answer is still valid if you want to get rid of all of the special characters within a string